# Setting Up Git With A Network Drive And Rsync

Tags: git, repository, rsync

I have a computer for development, a network drive, and a server that runs a website.

Network drive: I think I should have a repository on the network drive and checkout files to that drive when they are ready for the website. Is there a difference between checking out files from a bare repository versus having a working directory? If so, what is better?

Server: I think I should use rsync to copy the checked out files to the website directory.

Dev computer: Do I work directly on the files on the network drive, or do I have a separate repository? Preferably, I would have just the files I want to newly edit on this computer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Preferably, I would have just the files I want to newly edit on this computer.

That's exactly the opposite of how Git works. Git is a distributed version control system: *all* files and the complete history of all files is stored in *every* copy of the repository. This has quite a few advantages, including the ability to work offline.

You would probably have three repo's. Store the primary Git repository on the network drive as a bare repository, then push and pull from there from normal repositories on both the development machine and the server. Push from the development machine to the central repository when you're done coding; pull from the central repository on the server when you want to deploy.

You won't need rsync.